# Merged account, cannot access Email settings

Tags: support, status-completed, email, profile-page

Trying to access my email settings page I am redirected to an error page:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/2986984

I had merged 2 accounts, thus I had 2 email adresses. I deleted one, but it still kept being used for subscribing to tags. That old email adress is still floating around somewhere in my account data without me being able to see, modify or delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email settings page broke. A fix for this is rolling out in the next build (rev `2017.11.29.27887`).

Comment: Should I change the question to "email settings page broke", and then add a new question for the obsolete email address?

Comment: I did a quick check. Tag subscriptions are a separate thing (for now, were working on improving that experience). You're still subscribed to [tag:java] with you old email address, but that's on stackexchange.com -> https://stackexchange.com/users/2078462/user1851135?tab=subscriptionshttps://stackexchange.com/users/2078462/user1851135?tab=subscriptions

Comment: My problem is that any *new* subscription I do still sends a confirmation to my *old* email address. And while I later can manage subscriptions to choose new email address, I still don't get a confirmation to my new email address, nor any update emails. I want to use only gmail, in case you can fix that.

Comment: hmn yes, add a separate bug report for that please